# if there is a way to get the local timezone of the bigquery server?

Tags: google-bigquery

Recently ive been looking into [timestamp functions](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#timestampfunctions) and I'm curious if there is a way to get the local timezone of the server through `java Api`

Thanks in advance: Attila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp functions are all UTC.

Comment: Thanks but then why is this there?:
"These functions operate on the server's local time zone."

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've filed a doc bug. The functions are all UTC (which is why UTC is in the name of the time functions, in order to make that apparent)

Comment: I've found something i don't want to open a new ticket for,
I don't know if its intended or its by mistake that this function doesn't give back the Project with id "Publicdata"
Bigquery.projects().list().execute().getProjects()

the Bigquery instance is authorized through service account

Comment: getPorojects doesn't return all projects you have access to, only projects where you're explicitly listed as a project team member (e.g. owner/reader/writer)

Comment: Could you please correct the documentation then pls:


Lists the projects to which you have at least read access. Create a request for the method "projects.list". This request holds the parameters needed by the the bigquery server. After setting any optional parameters, call the List.execute() method to invoke the remote operation.

There is nothing about being explicitly listed as a project team member. It just says that it list out all projects i have at least read access for. i have read access for publicdata since its public.

Comment: Regarding publicdata, you don't have access to the project -- you have access to the dataset under that project. I agree we can be clearer on the docs though. I'll file the doc bug.